# Automapper doesn't perform JOINs when wrapped in Select()

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Consider i have following database query:

```cs
var entries = (await db.ScheduleEntries
    .Where(se => se.ClassId == studentsClassId)
    .OrderBy(se => se.LessonNumber)
    .Select(se => new
    {
        se.DayOfWeek,
        Entry = new ScheduleEntryDto
        {
            Id = se.Id,
            LessonNumber = se.LessonNumber,
            HostTeacher = se.EntryStub.TeacherFullname,
            Location = se.EntryStub.Location,
            SchoolClass = $"{se.Class.ClassNumber} {se.Class.ClassLetter}",
            SubjectName = se.EntryStub.Subject.Name
            // And other fields
            // But ScheduleEntryDto doesn't contain DayOfWeek field
        }
    })
    .ToArrayAsync())
    .GroupBy(rse => rse.DayOfWeek)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.Entry).ToArray());
```

EF Core produces nice SQL query which performs necessary `JOIN's` and grabs only required fields using `SELECT`.

But this code looks huge, doesn't it? So I decided to create an automapper profile to map db ScheduleEntry model to ScheduleEntryDto:

```cs
var entries = (await db.ScheduleEntries
    .Where(se => se.ClassId == studentsClassId)
    .OrderBy(se => se.LessonNumber)
    .Select(se => new
    {
        se.DayOfWeek,
        Entry = mapper.Map<ScheduleEntryDto>(se)
    })
    .ToArrayAsync())
    .GroupBy(rse => rse.DayOfWeek)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.Entry).ToArray());
```

But this code fails with 'A Command Is Already In Progress' exception. And it also produces strange SQL without any `JOIN's`.

The possible solution that i found - is to `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` all required tables, but i have to write all the Includes myself and it also produces SQL query that grabs a lot of unnecessary fields. And these Includes makes code huge once again.

I found that if `.Map<>()` is wrapped in a `.Select()` method the way I did it, EF Core doesn't perform necessary `JOIN's`.

But if I first `.ProjectTo()`, evaluate query, and then perform `.GroupBy()` DayOfWeek, everything works fine. But `ScheduleEntryDto` doesn't contain DayOfWeek field, so I can't do that.

So what shoud I do?

Comment: That select it translated into sql performed on the database. Automapper is a local thing and must be executed locally. So presumably you need todo that after ToArrayAsync().

Comment: Everything that you can do is complicated, if it is one place, do not use Automapper here. It is advise from AM creator, if library not suitable for your case - do not use it.

Comment: 1.Try to create a temporary dto that includes both the `ScheduleEntryDto` properties and the `DayOfWeek` field which named for example `ScheduleEntryWithDayDto`.
2.Modify the query to use `ProjectTo<ScheduleEntryWithDayDto>()` . 3. After retrieving the results, you can group by DayOfWeek, map to ScheduleEntryDto.

Answer (score 0):

When querying with EF the database isnt queried until there is a prompt such as '.ToList()', '.ToListAsync()' and in your case the prompt looks to be '.ToArrayAsync()' so what youre asking is for EF to generate a SQL from automapper which isnt possible, syntacticaly in your IDE it would be correct but EF cannot support that.

In my opinion theres nothing wrong with the initial query other than maybe try use a split query if its over several tables, but this can sometimes return different results so its worth testing.

[EF split query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)